# In tomcat - context in server.xml (url and resource location mapping) is not working in web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, web

When I am trying to call the ***mapped url*** in `web.xml`, then the browser shows the resource is not available.On the other hand,if we enter the mapped url manually via browser it works fine.

I think `web.xml` (container) is loaded before the context specified in the host in `server.xml`

Help me to find reason and suggest me the solution to overcome this.

Comment: How do you call the mapped URL from web.xml - don't know what you mean. Can you post your server.xml (the individual part) as well as your web.xml and provide an URL example that works in browser but not the other way?

Comment: Please give some precision as required by swinkler. Currently your question is unclear and likely to be closed.

Comment: @swinkler thanks for ur immediate response. this happens when i am trying place my login page out of my webapp i.e login-config param in web container and i proceed with the context in server.xml

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for ur immediate response - at first i configured a html page out of web-app and mapped that file in context in server.xml. Then i am trying to access the url with login-config in web container. This is what i have done